# Wifi randomly turning itself off MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, hardware

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2012. I always had the common connectivity issues with wifi but now its beyond my comprehension. My wifi turns itself off randomly. Sometimes it works fine for days, other times the problem happens all day. It started when my Bluetooth speaker caused interference with the wifi signal causing it to run slow or disconnecting itself either the speaker or the wifi.

Then one day the computer wifi started turning itself on and off every couple of seconds. I shut down the computer reseted the PRAM then wifi showed the crossed out icon with wifi:not configured message. Shut it down again did a SMC reset and a clean install of OS X now the problem appears randomly most of the time a reset will restore wifi but it shut itself off whenever it wants.

Any solutions or ideas?

Comment: This happens to me at a minor level, nothing to serious to what you are facing. Seems like your Wifi card is damaged.

Comment: I think I have the same issue. Do you have a message in the *Console* application saying `29/01/2017 14:52:43,207 corecaptured[95716]: doSaveChannels@286: Will write to: /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/CoreCapture/IOReporters/[2017-01-29_14,52,18.893310] - DriverState.xml` ?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.  I had this same problem with my 2012 Macbook Pro. My WiFi would lose connection, and I would have to turn it off and then back on to regain the connection.  Then it started giving me the "WiFi not configured" message when I would turn it back on. Sometimes a reboot, or PRAM reset, or several reboots/resets would resolve it for a little while.

I will say there does not seem to be an easy fix.  Mine started having this problem when I installed Yosemite; my hunch (at least for my case which was very similar) is that is is a software/driver issue and not a hardware issue.  Call apple tech support.

I will say that mine was out of warranty, but they still helped me; they put me in touch with their engineers to work on the problem, gave me software diagnostic tools to figure out what was happening, and eventually were able to resolve my problem. They went to great lengths, and I am no longer working on a computer that has this issue thanks to them.